# Render View Via Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I need to use bootstrap modal to load form , how I can call bootstrap modal with parameters via link ?

View:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(Yii::t('app','addaction'),'#myModal',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','data-toggle'=>'modal')) ;?>
<br/><br/><br/>

<!-- Bootstrap modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo Yii::t('app','AddAction'); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model,'productId'=>$productId));  // I need $productId to by dynamic related to link 
                ?>              
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Controller :

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
    $model=new Actions;
    $productId=intval($_GET['productId']);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Actions']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Actions'];

        $model->product_id=$productId;
        if($model->validate()){
            $model->save(false);
            $message=Email::setJavaMessage('success',Yii::t('app','sm'),Yii::t('app','actionWasAdded'));
            echo CJSON::encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=>$message));
            Yii::app()->end();
        }else{
            $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
            if($error!='[]')
                echo $error;
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
    if(Yii::app()->request->getIsAjaxRequest())
        echo $this->renderPartial('_form',array('model'=>$model,'productId'=>$productId),false,true);//This will bring out the view along with its script.

    else
        $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,'productId'=>$productId));
}
```

So with above code form is work with validation also, the problem if I need to add dynamic parameters to link how to ?
For example : use it in CRGidview via update function then the $product_id will change for every row related to values in database .

Comment: you missed 'data-target' attribute on your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you already found a solution but here is how I would do it:

In your link add a parameter like "data-productId" (for example: `CHtml::link('Addaction','#myModal',array('id'=>'link','data-toggle' => 'modal','data-productId'=>$id, 'class' => 'link'))`).

Bind a javascript function to the click event on your link like this:

```
$("a#link").click(function()
{
   var productId = $(this).data('productId');

   //you can change the value of a form component like this
   //in the below example I have a hidden input field whose val I want to change to be submitted with the form
   $("input#FormId_idHiddenInput").val(productId);

   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

For this example to work you would have to move your form from the partial to your dialog file.

Let me know if this helps you or if there are other problems you encounter.